# How do I turn a categorical value into column name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new at Javascript, and I am having problems with a list of dictionaries. I have an object such as this one:

```
0:{Year: "2007", expenditure: "314,448.7", category: "Exports"}
1:{Year: "2008", expenditure: "320,805.2", category: "Exports"}
2:{Year: "2007", expenditure: "314,448.7", category: "Imports"}
3:{Year: "2008", expenditure: "320,805.2", category: "Imports"}
```

and I would like to turn it into a new one with the values Exports and Imports as two different columns, with its correspondent expenditure below. Something like this:

```
0:{Year: "2007", Exports: "314,448.7"}
1:{Year: "2008", Exports: "320,805.2"}
2:{Year: "2007", Imports: "314,448.7"}
3:{Year: "2008", Imports: "320,805.2"}
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: FYI In JavaScript these are not dictionaries, they're Objects

Comment: @barmar today you are closing everything. The dupe seems to be just slightly related.

Comment: @JonasW. Unless he doesn't know how to loop over an array, what other problem could he have than creating a new object with a dynamic property name?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my question. What I would like to get is something like this: 0:{Year: "2007", Exports: "314,448.7", Imports: "314,448.7"}
                               1:{Year: "2008", Exports: "320,805.2", Imports: "320,805.2"}

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good job for [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
let arry = [{
    Year: "2007",
    expenditure: "314,448.7",
    category: "Exports"
  },
  {
    Year: "2008",
    expenditure: "320,805.2",
    category: "Exports"
  },
  {
    Year: "2007",
    expenditure: "314,448.7",
    category: "Imports"
  },
  {
    Year: "2008",
    expenditure: "320,805.2",
    category: "Imports"
  }
]

let result = arry.reduce((r, v) => r.concat([{
  Year: v.Year,
  [v.category]: v.expenditure
}]), [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `map` be even easier?

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize that it returned a new array. For some reason I thought it modified the array in place.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const output = input.map(({Year, expenditure, category}) => ({Year, [category]: expenditure }));
```

Just destructure every object and build up a new one. You can also include all other propertues in the new object using rest/spread:

```
 const output = input.map(({expenditure, category, ...rest}) => ({[category]: expenditure, ...rest }));
```

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn map returns a new array, and the OP asked to transform the current array into the two key one.